# Send GET Variables though several pages

Tags: php, html, forms, variables, url

I have recently been making a signup form for a website.
I have set 3 pages for the signup process:
Page 1 has a email and password form , when the user submits this it goes to page 2 in the GET format `https:example.com/page2.html?email=email@example.com&password=example`
Then on page 2 it gives the user a load of options to select , then posts that data to page 3 that executes a load of PHP commands based on the results , however I cannot think how to send the variables from page 1 along with page 2 to page 3.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the page two, make the hidden inputs, with the inputs of the page 1.

Like this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $_GET['email'];?>">
<input type="hidden" name="password" value="<?php echo $_GET['password'];?>">
```

In this way you will get these inputs again when the second page form is submitted.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the session feature in PHP.

http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

This way you can link info to a users session. Usually sessions last until the user closes the browser.

This way you also don't have to increase the data a user has to post towards your webserver.